# Updates of pyOpenSSL and pandas using 'pip' fail with "TypeError: resolve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'replace_conflicting'"

Tags: python, pandas, installation, pip, pyopenssl

When I attempt to update or install any version of `pandas` or `pyOpenSSL`(with any instance of `sudo pip --[un]install|update [--no-use-wheel] [pandas|pyOpenSSL|xattr|stevedore]`, using `pip` 1.5.4) I get:

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/pandas
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Rax/Library/Logs/pip.log
...
TypeError: resolve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'replace_conflicting'
```

Why am I getting this error and what can I do to avoid it?

---

OSX 10.9.2; Python 2.7.5; `setuptools` 3.4.3.

More detail on the error report (for `pandas`):

```
Downloading/unpacking pandas
  Downloading pandas-0.13.1.tar.gz (6.1MB): 6.1MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pandas/setup.py) egg_info for package pandas
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pandas/setup.py", line 590, in <module>
        **setuptools_kwargs)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 239, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 264, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True
    TypeError: resolve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'replace_conflicting'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/pandas/setup.py", line 590, in <module>

    **setuptools_kwargs)

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup

    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 239, in __init__

    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 264, in fetch_build_eggs

    replace_conflicting=True

TypeError: resolve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'replace_conflicting'
```

Contents of `/Users/Rax/Library/Logs/pip.log`:

```
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 274, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1215, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 321, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 697, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/pandas
```

---

```
Cython          - 0.20.1       - active 
Flask           - 0.10.1       - active 
Jinja2          - 2.7.2        - active 
MarkupSafe      - 0.19         - active 
PyRSS2Gen       - 1.1          - active 
Pygments        - 1.6          - active 
Python          - 2.7.5        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload)
Sphinx          - 1.2.2        - active 
Twisted         - 13.2.0       - active 
Werkzeug        - 0.9.4        - active 
altgraph        - 0.11         - active 
astropy         - 0.3          - active 
backports.ssl-match-hostname - 3.4.0.2      - active 
bdist-mpkg      - 0.5.0        - active 
brewer2mpl      - 1.3.2        - active 
cffi            - 0.8.2        - active 
colorama        - 0.2.7        - active 
configobj       - 5.0.1        - active 
dill            - 0.2b1        - active 
distribute      - 0.7.3        - active 
docutils        - 0.11         - active 
ggplot          - 0.4.7        - active 
ipython         - 1.2.1        - active 
itsdangerous    - 0.23         - active 
macholib        - 1.6          - active 
matplotlib      - 1.3.1        - active 
modulegraph     - 0.11         - active 
mpltools        - 0.1          - active 
nose            - 1.3.0        - active 
numexpr         - 2.3.1        - active 
numpy           - 1.8.0        - active 
numpydoc        - 0.4          - active 
pandas          - 0.13.1       - active 
patsy           - 0.2.1        - active 
pika            - 0.9.13       - active 
pip             - 1.5.4        - active 
prettytable     - 0.7.2        - active 
progressbar     - 2.2          - active 
py2app          - 0.8          - active 
pycparser       - 2.10         - active 
pyparsing       - 2.0.1        - active 
python-dateutil - 2.2          - active 
pytz            - 2014.1.1     - active 
pyzmq           - 14.0.1       - active 
readline        - 6.2.4.1      - active 
rpy2            - 2.3.9        - active 
scikit-learn    - 0.14.1       - active 
scipy           - 0.13.3       - active 
setuptools      - 3.4.3        - active 
sphinx-argparse - 0.1.9        - active 
sphinxcontrib-napoleon - 0.2.6        - active 
sphinxcontrib-programoutput - 0.8          - active 
statsmodels     - 0.5.0        - active 
stevedore       - 0.14.1       - active 
sympy           - 0.7.5        - active 
tornado         - 3.2          - active 
virtualenv-clone - 0.2.4        - active 
virtualenv      - 1.11.4       - active 
virtualenvwrapper - 4.2          - active 
websocket-client - 0.12.0       - active 
wsgiref         - 0.1.2        - active development (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7)
xattr           - 0.7.4        - active 
yhat            - 0.6.14       - active 
yolk            - 0.4.3        - active 
zope.interface  - 4.0.5        - active
```

---

FWIW, I can install `pandas` successfully in a virtual environment. If I copy it from there back into the environment where I get this error and run `nosetests pandas` I get:

```
..SS..SS..SS..SS/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py:910: RuntimeWarning: tp_compare didn't return -1 or -2 for exception
  result.sort()
..SS..SS..SS..SS..SSSSSSSSSS..SS..SS..SSSS.S.S...........SS..SS..SS..........................SSSSSSSSSS.SSSS.....SSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS.SSSS..................S.....S........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................SS......................................................................................................SSSS.......................SSS..............................................................................................................................................S.......................SSSSSSS...........................................................................................S......................................................................................................................................................S.........................................S..S..S....S........................................................S......S.S.......S...S..S............S............................................................................................................................................................................................S............................................................................S........................................./Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:55: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice.", RuntimeWarning)
...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................S...............................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4466 tests in 230.555s

OK (SKIP=330)
```

This is also what I get if I run the tests in the virtual environment.

Comment: Can you do a ($pip freeze) to see what other packages you have?  Is this only happening for ($pip install pandas --upgrade) or are you having issues with other package installations/upgrades as well?

Comment: @Will: Output from `freeze` added above (after uninstalling `pandas`) while testing other versions other variations of `pip --[un]install|update [--no-use-wheel] pandas`, all of which fail in the same way, only for `pandas` (among the recently updated packages I've tried).

Comment: Hmm, that's really weird.  Mines similar to yours for all the necessary libraries (e.g. Cython), the only difference is that you have pyobjc-framework.  Does setting up a virtualenv and then installing pandas work there?  I'm just guessing at this point, but did you install homebrew or did you modify your bash_profile recently?

Comment: @Will: The only recent change was updating to the current Cython when it was released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [likely cause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23122121/656912) is the presence of multiple versions of `setuptools`, with an older version earlier on the Python path than the newer one. This can be temporarily overcome for the purposes of installation by beginning your invocations of `pip` with

```
PYTHONPATH=/PATH_TO_YOUR_CURRENT_PACKAGES/site-packages pip ...
```

---

You can confirm that this is the case by executing

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.__file__
```

in Python and noting that the `pkg_resources.pyc` returned is *not* in the location of your current site packages.

In some cases this can also be corrected by ensuring that the `pkg_resources.pyc` in your site packages directory in executed, rather than the one in your system packages directory (e.g., by deleting the latter).

Answer (score -1):

If you are on OSX, the easiest solution in my opinion to avoid errors like you are having is to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to manage the installation of Python, pip and libraries like pandas.

If you are already using Homebrew (it was unclear from your question). Try running `brew doctor` and see if there are any reported errors.

To get `pip` working in concert with Homebrew:

- `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"` to install Homebrew.
- `brew doctor` and make sure you get no errors from running this command. Follow what it recommends, especially concerning the `$PATH` environment variable.
- `brew install python` to install Python 2.7 (and pip)
- `pip install pandas`

Comment: But it is *not* clear from the question that you are using a `pip` that was installed with Homebrew. When you install Python using *Homebrew*, then you can use `pip` without `sudo` and everything should just *work* See: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python. Just from experience, using a **brewed** Python and a **brewed** pip, you tend to avoid package installation errors like you encountered above.

Comment: I don't use homebrew. But let's see where this goes: how do I get from an established Python installation using `pip` to one that uses *Homebrew*?

Comment: BTW, I suspect that *Hombrew* is not, in fact, going to make a difference. I suspect that `numpy` needs to be rebuilt using the latest Cython.

Comment: See my edited answer. You are probably right about having to rebuild `numpy`. That would be trivial to do with Homebrew as well.

Comment: I've updated the error report and added more detail about the error message I see. Rebuilding `numpy` does not help.

Comment: I also removed all the `pyobjc` packages for good measure and have uncovered the same issue with installing `pyOpenSSL` (though not other packages).

Comment: any luck with homebrew?

Comment: I'm not going that path yet. For a bunch of reasons I don't want a package manger (other than pip), so the solution needs to fix the system I have.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48205/discussion-between-william-denman-and-raxacoricofallapatorius)