# Can I move a package from a virtualenv to my system packages as a stopgap?

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, pip

Occasionally, I [run into glitches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21678394/656912) installing or updating Python packages on my system using `pip` (on OS X) but find that I can install the troublesome packages in a virtualenv (that employs the same version of Python as my system) and then copy them over to my system packages, where they seem to work fine.

Is there any reason not to do this (at least as a stopgap for packages I urgently need)? Does the package installed in the virtualenv incorporate any information about the virtualenv that would cause it to misbehave among the system packages (e.g. if the virtualenv was deleted)? Will information about the presence of the copied package be missing from the system installation (i.e., is there information saved there about the packages that have been installed other than what's in the packages themselves)?

Comment: Note, this is not a question about finding other ways (e.g. Homebrew) to manages packages on OS X. It's just about whether one can move successfully installed packages around in this way.

Comment: It's not a very good idea to mess around with your system Python distribution in that way, but as long as the two Pythons use the same version you will probably get away with it. However it might be better to investigate why they install isn't working on your main system Python. The usual reason for such issues is the inability of an ordinary user to write into directories like /usr/lib/PythonX/site-packages.

If this is the case then presumably your installations would run correctly if you ran them with `sudo` (assuming you are on a *nix system).

Comment: @holdenweb: What's causing the problem is a separate question. And I'm aware of the general warnings about messing with system Python. The question here is specific to (a) exactly what a package retains about the content in which it was installed, and (b) what an installation knows about the packages installed there (beyond what's embodied in the packages themselves).

Comment: @holdenweb: If the answer to (a) "just the version of Python that was used" and to (b) "nothing"? That's how things seem to behave, and if that's true, I'm guessing things ought to be pretty safe. (In fact, it seems like a decent security policy: `pip` can be run in the virtual env w/o `sudo`.) But I'm guessing it's not (at least not always) that simple.