# What does the error "resolve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'replace_conflicting'" mean?

Tags: python, installation, package, pip, conflict

When I update certain packages in my Python installation using `pip` I get

```
TypeError: resolve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'replace_conflicting'
```

I get this error for certain packages and not others, and [have asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21678394/656912) about ways to work around it (ideally while continuing to use `pip`) in the specific cases where I encounter it; but the question here is what the error means in the first place and what might be the likely cause.

What does this error mean and what could be causing it?

---

```
Downloading/unpacking xattr
  Downloading xattr-0.7.5.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/xattr/setup.py) egg_info for package xattr
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/xattr/setup.py", line 67, in <module>
        cmdclass={'build': cffi_build},
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 239, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 264, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True
    TypeError: resolve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'replace_conflicting'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/xattr/setup.py", line 67, in <module>

    cmdclass={'build': cffi_build},

  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup

    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 239, in __init__

    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))

  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 264, in fetch_build_eggs

    replace_conflicting=True

TypeError: resolve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'replace_conflicting'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by having two different versions of setuptools: one in `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7` and another in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. Somehow, `setuptools.dist.Distribution.fetch_build_eggs` in  the newer version calls `pkg_resources.working_set.resolve` from the older version. The old version of resolve doesn't support the replace_conflicting argument.

On my OS X Lion machine, I was able to fix the problem like this:

```
$ sudo python /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/easy_install.py -U setuptools
$ sudo easy_install -U pip
```

That is, I used the old version of easy_install to upgrade easy_install and then used that to upgrade pip.

This fixed the problem on my system because it modified `sys.path` so that the new version of `pkg_resources` under `/Library/Python` loaded before the old version which can still be found under `/System/Library/Frameworks`. An alternative workaround might be to modify `sys.path` temporarily using the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, see [the Python manual](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).

Comment: This seems like a bug in `setuptools`. There's no way it should be reaching out the current version should calling into the older version in a different location.

Comment: Perhaps. Before running the commands above, after `import pkg_resources`, `pkg_resources.__file__` was `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.pyc`. After running the commands, it's `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-3.4.4-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.pyc`. I think it has to do with sys.path settings on the Mac.

Comment: I worked up the courage to try the commands you suggest — and got the *same error*: `ypeError: resolve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'replace_conflicting'`!

Comment: Hmm. Maybe your problem was different than mine or something's different in our pip/easy_install configuration. Do you have two copies of pkg_resources.pyc, one under /System/Library/Frameworks and one under /Library/Python? What is the value of pkg_resources.__file__?

Comment: The value of `pkg_resources.__file__` is `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.pyc`. In addition to that one, I have one at `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.pyc` (and a corresponding `.py`).

Comment: Is there something I can do to get the "wrong" one of these out of sight so that (at least for the package installation process) it is not seen?

Comment: The problem continues with `setuptools` 4.0.1.

Comment: After running the commands above, my sys.path starts out like this: ['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-3.4.4-py2.7.egg', ... That is, the setuptools egg comes before standard locations. I think that's what really fixed things. I wouldn't call it an ideal solution, but it's all I've got. It looks like your easy_install didn't install setuptools as an egg, but mine did. OS X gives eggs priority in sys.path, which is why this fixed the version mismatch for me.

Comment: So if I could modify my `sys.path` (at least for the package installation process) I might be able to get things working again. Is there a way to provide a modified `sys.path` to `pip`?

Comment: Try `PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages pip ...` which should put the location of your new setuptools at or near the beginning of sys.path for that run.